# Can method 1 pass kwargs to method 2?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I want kwargs to have the same exact contents in method2 as whatever gets passed into method1.  In this case "foo" is passed into method1 but I want to pass in any arbitrary values and see them in kwargs in both method1 and method2.  Is there something I need to do differently with how I call method2?

```
def method1(*args,**kwargs):

    if "foo" in kwargs:
        print("method1 has foo in kwargs")

    # I need to do something different here
    method2(kwargs=kwargs)

def method2(*args,**kwargs):

    if "foo" in kwargs:
        # I want this to be true
        print("method2 has foo in kwargs")

method1(foo=10)
```

Output:

```
method1 has foo in kwargs
```

Desired output:

```
method1 has foo in kwargs
method2 has foo in kwargs
```

Let me know if I need to clarify what I'm asking, or if this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keyword expansion.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
method2(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def method1(*args,**kwargs):
    if "foo" in kwargs:
        print("method1 has foo in kwargs")

    method2(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called unpacking argument lists. The python.org doc is [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).  In your example, you would implement it like this.

```
def method1(*args,**kwargs):      
    if "foo" in kwargs:         
        print("method1 has foo in kwargs")      

    # I need to do something different here     
    method2(**kwargs) #Notice the **kwargs.  

def method2(*args,**kwargs):      
    if "foo" in kwargs:         # I want this to be true         
        print("method2 has foo in kwargs")  

method1(foo=10)
```